# Running test with "usbtest" on Ubuntu

Tags: module, usb, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-14.04

i am newbie to these modules and device drivers and all.I would like run some sample tests on ubuntu main tree USB driver. I have seen [this](http://www.linux-usb.org/usbtest/) document and was trying to do the same.I do inserted the "usbtest" module and while trying to run

> usbtest

command, terminal says the command not found

I have tried to insert g_zero module by running

> modprobe g_zero

,but it says

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'g_zero': No such device

and

> modprobe --force g_zero says
>
> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'g_zero': Exec format error

Anyone Please post better simple explanation..

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and my kernel is 3.13.0-24-generic

Also please suggest any method to test linux main tree drivers through command line.

Comment: What are you trying to test: UDC or USB host functionality?

Comment: I want to test USB Host Controller Drivers... in other words i need to test the kernel main tree drivers..

Comment: Kernel main tree drivers contain both UDC and USB host drivers. This one doesn't answer to my question. First part looks like USB host you need to test. Then you need dummy module inside USB subsystem which usually used for that. `g_*` modules as far as I understand refers to USB Gadget framework.